# join array items into one string for a label in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

In my app I have an array coming back from an API and currently it is creating a new label for each item and stacking them one on top of another. I would like it to create one label where the array items are in string separated by a bullet. Here is my current working code:

```
lblLeft.text = ""

if let expertiseCount = helper.expertise {
    for i in 0..<expertiseCount.count {
        if i >= 0 {
            print(expertiseCount[i].name!)
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10
            let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: lblLeft.text! + "\(expertiseCount[i].name ?? "")\n")
            attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
            lblLeft.attributedText = attrString        
        }
    }
}
```

currently looks like the image on the left, I want it to look like the image on the right.[image]

Comment: remove your "\n" and add  `paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking in account that your `Expertise` class `.name` is what you need to concat, you can use `map` and after that as @Andrii answer suggest use `join` and finally adjusting the `paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode`, replace your code by this one

```
if let expertiseCount = helper.expertise {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    let finalString = expertiseCount.map({$0.name}).joined(separator: " • ")
    let finalAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: finalString, attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle])
    lblLeft.attributedText = finalAttributedString
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you, I am getting an error that says " value of type '[Skill]' has no member 'name' " but I am not sure why?? Your comment above (remove your "\n" and add paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping) did work for me though.

Comment: What is helper.expertise an array of what? @jessicamele

Comment: this is the example that i was given that the api sends: [{contentType=application/json, example={
  "data" : [ {
    "min_call_time" : 5,
    "rate" : "aeiou",
    "total_revenue" : "aeiou",
    "profile_pic" : "aeiou",
    "about" : "aeiou",
    "num_calls" : 1,
    "available_now" : true,
    "id" : 0,
    "screenname" : "aeiou",
    "expertise" : [ {
      "name" : "aeiou",
      "id" : 5
    } ],
    "feedback_score" : "aeiou",
    "feedback_count" : 6
  } ]
}}] Not sure if that is helpful, I'm new to this and am trying to wrap my head around things.

Comment: @jessicamele check my updated answer and let me know

Comment: @ ReinierMelian I had to change ({$0.name}) to {{$0.name!}} and lblLeft.text = finalAttributedString to lblLeft.text = finalAttributedString.string and that did the trick, many thanks!

Comment: @jessicamele better lblLeft.attributedText = finalAttributedString, I am glad to help you, please if my answer helps you upvote and accept my answer

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to loop over your `expertiseCount` array. Arrays of strings in Swift have a special method `joined(separator:)`, which should do exactly what you need:

```
let joinedExpertise = expertiseCount.joined(" • ")
```

Use a special bullet point character, `•`, as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your code like this:

```
if let expertise = helper.expertise {
    let expertises = expertise.joined(" • ") // join the strings with bullet point char

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping // line break by word wrappnig

    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: expertises)
    attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: 0..<attrString.characters.count) // not sure i this range will work, change to fit your needs
    lblLeft.attributedText = attrString
}
```

This code wasn't tested but you got the idea...

Answer (score 0):

***Swift 5***

if you want to set a single string to a label in loop, you can follow this simple method.

```
for hash in objSinglePost?.hash_tags ?? [Hashtags].init() {
            self.lblHashtags.text = (self.lblHashtags.text ?? "") + " #" + (hash.hash_tags ?? "")
        }
```